# Gerar automaticamente procedures com campo tipo table-type no Entity-framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

estou tentando gerar um banco ja existente para Entity-framework 5,consegui gerar sem problemas,com todos os relacionamentos porem nesse banco tenho procedures que recebe como parametro um table-type mas quando vou fazer chamada dessas procedures que tem esse tipo de parametro o EF ignora o parametro.

Gostaria de saber como faço para que ele gerar automaticamente e aceite esses paremetros nas procedures ja existentes no sistema.

Minha procedures :

```
Alter PROC ListarCursosV2
    @usuarioID INT
    , @cultura VARCHAR(11)='pt-BR'
    ,  @dominios SubDominio READONLY
AS
```

Chamada da proc:

```
var Cursos = context.ListarCursosV2(usuarioID, "pt-BR");
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157345/entity-framework-stored-procedure-table-value-parameter

Comment: Pelo que eu achei na internet na versão 4.5 do EF ,ele ja tem suporte para esse tipo de parametro,estou errado?